# I did Udemy course on MERN stack. Please suggest some projects for my resume in order to apply for internship

Tags: reactjs, mern, react-fullstack

Please suggest some projects based on MERN stack that will look on my resume. I will afterwards apply for internships or entry level full stack dev jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build these projects it'll help you learn something new

> *Ecommerce site :-* you will learn rendering technicians and also how to design APIs you can also integrate payments

> *Real-time chat App :-* It will help you learn about web sockets and real-time data

> *Blog Site :-*  Build a fully functional blog application for learning about routing, static rendering, dynamic rendering

**Best thing to build is just re-build some papular site and also try new JS frameWorks like Next-Js, remix and any other**